# How one can simulate a system given by differential equation?

Tags: simulation, numerical-modelling, differential-equations

I want to simulate a diffusion environment given by the differential equation 
$$\frac{\partial u(x,y,t)}{\partial t}=D\left(\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y,t)}{\partial y^2}\right),$$
in a constrained environment with reflecting and absorbing boundaries and certain initial conditions. I know it may be done with the help of particle simulation method. But I want to know is there a way, in general, to obtain numerically the concentration profile $u(x,y,t)$   by using directly the differential equations?

I am actually trying to verify some of the ambiguities. I have used the particle simulation method to verify obtained PDF (normalized concentration profile for my case) but it gives me different results and I am not sure whether particle simulation method is correct to validate the obtained result?

Comment: Yes, there are several methods to obtain the solution numerically.

Comment: @nicoguaro Can you suggest a reference where I can get these methods?

Comment: What have you already tried? You are trying to numerically solve a partial differential equation. Googling for this expression would be a good start :-)

Comment: I would suggest: Langtangen, Hans Petter, and Svein Linge. [Finite difference computing with PDEs: a modern software approach.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319554556) Vol. 16. Springer, 2017.